# How to determine the value of an SMD coil?

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, coil

I am trying to repair one PCB where an SMD coil seems to be burned out.

I would like to replace this component, but I have no idea about how to determine the value of this SMD device, because it is not marked.

How can I get this value?

[image][image]

Comment: You could try rewinding it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an estimate by measuring the package size using calipers and then searching digikey to see what is the most popular value for that package size.  Err on the side of using a value that is too large.

Also, you could follow the traces to see what IC it is connected to, and then look at the reference schematic in the datasheet of that IC and see if it recommends an inductor value.

Comment: Package size will be as much a function of current rating and technology as inductance value.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Absolutely true, and very good point that current rating will be a critical factor when selecting a replacement inductor.

Comment: There are online calculators that you can use to estimate the inductance of the coil. Google inductor calculator ferrite rod. (I am assuming that your burned SMD coil has a ferrite core, if that is incorrect you may have to adjust search string accordingly.)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll end up with a huge list of possibilities with the first suggestion. Your second suggestion makes much more sense.

Comment: Measure the core dimensions, assume a resonable permitivity and you can calculate the Al for the core. Count the turns and your inductance is L=N^2*Al.